# Is there a way to combine more than two arrays just like array_combine does?

Tags: php, html

I am passing two variables from an HMTL form as arrays and i used array combine and for each loop to loop through all the two variables but now i need to pass through 3 variables so it is possible? my current code is below and am getting an error when i add a third variable.

```
array_combine($firstnumber, $secondnumber) as $firstnum => $secondnum)
{ //do something with the variables }
```

Comment: Please show real code, not pseudo code

Comment: `array_combine` takes keys from the first array and values from the second to make a new array with corresponding key/value pairs. There inherently could not be a function that performs the same action with three or more arrays as there are only two elements in play: a key and a value. If all you want is to make one array out of multiple then you want `array_merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_merge`, to join multiple arrays in PHP.

[PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php)

- array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values
- array_merge — Merge one or more arrays

Be aware! The behaviour of both is different.